# How to get not numeric nor letter characters on a table field on HANA

Tags: substring, hana

A little context first:
I'm working with DataServices, and I have a job that takes information from a Calculation View on HANA taking it to a .csv file. 
We were having some troubles with a field, which wasn't taking a customer's full name, so we had to concatenate first and last name.
Problem is that after that we got an error on DS: "-10427 Conversion of parameter/column (8) from data type VARCHAR1 to ASCII failed".
I've been reading around and I understand that it happens because there's some character in that particular field that is causing the error, but I don't know how I could get it.
My functional approach would be something like

`select characters_that_are_not_letters_nor_numbers_in_the_field from CV`

and from there try and change the possible conflicting characters in the CV so they won't become a problem.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that there are characters in the input that cannot be represented as `ASCII` characters. Most likely these characters are **UNICODE** characters.

The most common and appropriate response to such an issue - especially in relation to real-world data like *names* - is to go and **allow UNICODE characters**.

This can easily be achieved by using the correct data type, e.g. **N**VARCHAR.

If you don't want to allow UNICODE characters in your output, then you need to implement some explicit mapping - e.g. a projection that replaces any non-ASCII characters with suitable replacements.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, I would need to create a new column in the CV with the correct data type, right?
Other than that, how could I identify the characters that I should map?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLScript regular expression function LOCATE_REGEXPR](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/hana-database-sqlscript-regular-expression-function-for-alpha-numeric-characters.aspx) for locating characters matching to the regular expression provided

For example to find the first numeric character in a string, developers can use

```
locate_regexpr(START '[\p{N}]' IN :string )
```

I'm not sure if there is a short expression for special characters, but you can exclude letters p{L} and numeric characters p{N} to match special characters like punctuations, etc.